# SQL query doesn't get values

Tags: php, mysql

The SQL query returns just Array in the browser even if there is values in the database. I have tried the query in phpmyadmin and it works but not in my php document.

```
require_once('connect.php');

$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `questions` WHERE round='1' AND year='2016'";
$sql = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Almost the same query works in different php documents. Any suggestions what is wrong? Should also say that the query should return integers.

Comment: Can you show us what you are doing with the results please? With the $row variable

Comment: Yes, at this point just echo $row;

Comment: you need to loop over successful results and check for errors on the query and assuming a mysqli_ connection of course.

Comment: *Give it a minute or so*, someone's going to post an answer. Just my *Spidey sense tingling* ;-)

Comment: I have tried with while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $array[] = $row['id'];
}

Comment: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { echo $row['column_in_question']; }` - you need to "echo" here also. `column_in_question` is just an example here.

Comment: Question is really short on info that's why all the comments.

Comment: And seeing that you only select `id` that is the ONLY column in question.

Comment: ^ that too, should it be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `questions` WHERE round='1' AND year='2016'";
```

You're only selecting the `id` column. If you wish to echo more columns, then you need to add them in the query.

I.e.:

```
$query = "SELECT `id`, `col2`, `col3` FROM `questions` WHERE round=1 AND year=2016";
```

then loop over results:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    echo $row['id']; 
    // echo "<br>";
    // echo $row['col2'] . "<br>"; 
    // echo $row['col3'];
}
```

Check for errors on the query also and assuming a successful `mysqli_` connection.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Other reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: @HankyPanky I don't mind per se (thanks), however if the OP's columns are VARCHAR (which we don't know), then those might fail. TBH, I don't know if it would fail though. Most particularly `year=2016` but not for the `id`.

Comment: As long as the values provided in the query are numbers, they will work fine

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display other column's data so have to add `*` in the place of `'id'`

```
require_once('connect.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE round='1' AND year='2016'";
$sql = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
```

Comment: *"if you want to display other column's data so have to add \*"* - Not always recommended and could be a load if the table contains many many columns and could also fail for other reasons which is beyond the scope of the question. It's always best to choose the actual columns, rather than all. This is a suggestion if anything and not a solution for the question.